# locating node with eventListener in javascript object method

Tags: javascript, html

In the program I'm writing I need to be able to access the node that is sending an event in javascript.

I have been unsuccessful in using `this`, as it is referring to the object in my code. So the following doesn't work.

```
var node = new node();

// Node Object
function node() {

// Create Sibling Node
this.createSibling = function() {
 var node = createNode();
 this.parentNode.appendChild(node); } }
```

When I call the function `createNode()` it assembles a link that has an event `onclcick` attached to it called `node.createSibling()` and `node.createChild()` on a different link.

I'm currently using `var NODETREE` as the parent because I'm don't know how to get the node that is begin clicked. This is keeping me from being able to create node with their own children and siblings; only the main node can get them.

```
    var node = new node();

   // Node Object
   function node() {

   // Instance Veriables    
   var NODETREE = document.getElementById('node-tree');

   // Create Sibling Node
   this.createSibling = function() {
   var node = createNode();
   NODETREE.appendChild(node); } }
```

How do I access the node that has the `onclcick` event attached that is being clicked, without having to create a load of code, so I can create children and siblings for the nodes that I have created and not just the trunk?

**NOTE**:

I need to do this **without** jQuery or another framework.

Comment: I have found the article http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/ but I don't understand the code. It uses syntax I'm not familiar with. I'm new to JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element has an eventhandler the Event object is passed to the event handler. This event object has amongst other things a reference to the node that triggered the event.

So...

```
var createSibling = function(_event){
  var e = this; // the element this function is actually attached to
  var event_e = _event.target; //another way to get at the element clicked

  // do stuff
};

document.getElementById('myElement').onClick = createSibling;
document.getElementById('myElement').captureEvents(Event.CLICK);
```

The problem is the property names for different things differ cross browser - this is another reson to use a framework because they will implement the browser detection ans specific implementations which you will need to do if you do not use one.

See quirksmode.org for some advanced details:  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: Will this work with a method of an object? 'this.createSibling = function() { ... }' because when I use 'this' it retrieves the object 'new node();'

Comment: Wait i think youre getting confused (or youve gotten me confused). What is the Object? if its a DOMElement that holds the createSibling method then youd do something like `theElement.onclick = function(event){this.createSibling();};` So exactly what is the object and what is its relationship to the element thats triggering the event (the target if you will..)?

Comment: updated code base in main question for you, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the help your code worked! just took me a while to get my head around it.